# Issue in fetching data from db to the views in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, database, laravel, view, controller

Im new to laravel and studying it by creating some test projects myself in laravel 5.2. But i got stuck now with some issue in fetching data correctly from db in laravel 5.2 and display the result. I have a menu table in my db with fields -> id, menutype, itemname, itemprice, itemimage with some datas in it. I want to display it on my webpage in a specific way like as seen on the below given screenshot.

See: 
[image]

And this one is my db table screenshot with the values on it. See:
[image]

i added the below codes in my Controller (GuestController.php)

```
public function menu() {
    $result=DB::table('menu')->select('menutype')->distinct()->get();
    return view('guest.menu')->with('data',$result);                
}
```

and in the View (menu.blade.php), i had given the below code:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($data as $row)
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="wrap-col">
        <h3>{{$row->menutype}}</h3>
        <?php
        $item=DB::table('menu')->where('menutype', $row->menutype)->get();  
        ?>
        @foreach($item as $row)
        <div class="post">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/{{$row->itemimage}}"/></a>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h5><a href="#">{{$row->itemname}}</a></h5>
            <span>Rs.{{$row->itemprice}}/-</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This works perfectly and i am getting the desired output as seen on the products page screenshot given above. But i know this method is not correct, because i am giving the query statement on the View  itself like as given below to fetch data and its against the MVC concept:

```
<?php $item=DB::table('menu')->where('menutype', $row->menutype)->get(); ?>
```

So is there any other simple and better way i can implement to get the above said desired output along with keeping the MVC Standards?? Please help! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel's Collection can really help you out with this. Specifically, the `groupBy` method. First, you get all of the menu items with all the data. Then, you use the `groupBy` method on the Collection to group the menu items into separate arrays based on their `menutype`. You can then use this one Collection to do all the work in your view.

The code is shown below. You can combine a couple of the lines into one if you'd like, but it is broken out into multiple lines to show all the steps:

```
public function menu() {
    // get all the menu items
    $menuArray = DB::table('menu')->get();
    // create a Laravel Collection for the items
    $menuCollection = collect($menuArray);
    // group the Collection on the menutype field
    $groupedMenu = $menuCollection->groupBy('menutype');

    /**
     * Note that Eloquent queries (using Models) will automatically return
     * Collections, so if you have your Menu model setup, your first two
     * lines would just be:
     * $menuCollection = Menu::get();
     * or, all three lines could be combined into:
     * $groupedMenu = Menu::get()->groupBy('menutype');
     */

    // pass the grouped Collection to the view
    return view('guest.menu')->with('data', $groupedMenu);
}
```

Now, in your view, your outer foreach will iterate through the groups. The inner foreach will iterate through the items in each group:

```
<div class="row">
    @foreach($data as $type => $items)
    <div class="col-1-3">
      <div class="wrap-col">
        <h3>{{$type}}</h3>
        @foreach($items as $item)
        <div class="post">
          <a href="#"><img src="assets/images/{{$item->itemimage}}"/></a>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <h5><a href="#">{{$item->itemname}}</a></h5>
            <span>Rs.{{$item->itemprice}}/-</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
      </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. This works perfectly. Thanks man.... :) I think this method is more correct among the otherones posted by others here. This method is written straight forward  without any tricky coding in the view part. Thank you again.